# Are the 7 fundamental SI units able to differentiate between all elementary particles?

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, dimensional-analysis, quarks, si-units

More specifically, can the [7 base SI units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SI_base_unit) express qualities like quark strangeness (of quarks) and quark color? How do **these** SI units differentiate between different quarks (charm, up, top...)?

Comment: This is an excellent question? How can properties that distinguish particles be just numbers? These should be measurable and have physical dimensions. Anything quantised can be referred to by a number. Examples are spin and electromagnetic charge. These are measurable quantities with physical dimensions. Even the Schrödinger energy of a hydrogen state can be referred by just the principal quantum  number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Properties like the strangeness of a quark are just numbers with no dimension. Quark color is mostly related to a category than to a quantifiable thing, is like saying positive or negative, red or blue. The SI units may help to differentiate between different quarks by measuring the respective rest masses and electric charges (in Joules/c^2 or Kg, and Coulombs, if you wish).

Comment: Does this imply that strangeness (and other properties) can't actually be quantified by themselves and merely act as a reference to indicate other properties? Seems kind of weird to me... But this answer does begin to clear things up a bit. +1

Comment: If you check for the quark composition of strange particles, you will find that the strangeness is just how many valence strange quarks the particle has. If you ask me how many electrons are there in a helium atom, 2 is valid answer, I don't have to indicate any units.